# Magento 1.9 CE Hide Products in Upsell for certain Groups/Categories

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i am using Magento 1.9 CE and using some Upsell Products.

I have two Customer Groups - General and Retailer.

Retailer can see and buy all Products.
General can see all, but can´t buy all Products.

Now i have some Upsell Items and i want to show them only if the Customer Group can buy them.

Is there any way to do it?. In Magento Enterprise is the Option Rule-Based Product Relations is there anything like that for CE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override block with Upsells and modify query which fetches data from DB. 
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/